# Error An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker in Account Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first, dbcontext, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I need to change one value in Identity Users for specific user, but when i change i phase this error (An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker)?

The Unlock Account View Model as in the below code:

```cs
    public class AccountLockoutViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the code for ActionResult Unlock Account in the AccountController:

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UnlockAccount(AccountLockoutViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            var user =  UserManager.FindByName(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
                return RedirectToAction("UnlockAccountConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            else
            {

                user.LockoutEnabled = false;
                //Identitydb.Users.Attach(user);   <--- I tried this solution also but it is not work
                Identitydb.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified; //The error raised here
                Identitydb.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("UnlockAccountConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

The error raised as shown in this picture link: 
[Error raised location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFr5y.png)

I read many article and work too much in this case, but, until now i didn't find solution.

This some links I visit it: 
1- [Entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker in a generic repository](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/32738458/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker-in-a-generic-repository) 
2- [An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker](http://davecallan.com/entity-object-cannot-referenced-multiple-instances-ientitychangetracker/)
3- [An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" Exception Occur when adding value to the table using Entity Framework](https://forums.asp.net/t/2005885.aspx?%20An%20entity%20object%20cannot%20be%20referenced%20by%20multiple%20instances%20of%20IEntityChangeTracker%20Exception%20Occur%20when%20adding%20value%20to%20the%20table%20using%20Entity%20Framework)

Please write the solution if you understand the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How is `UserManager.FindByName` implemented. Ever tried there to use `.AsNoTracking()` when selecting the user?
Something like this: `context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(....)`
A using is Required for `AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: Hi Raupes, Thank you for reply, the UserManager.FindByName is implemented by Owin Library, The problem that i can't find the AsNoTracking() method, it is not come.

Comment: **Hi @Raupes,**
I tried to use `AsNoTracking()` method but the problem still same, _if you can provide me code_, so, i can try to solve this problem, this will be very helpful.

Comment: **Hi Raupes,**
This is the error I got it after trying your answer: _The entity type WhereListIterator`1 is not part of the model for the current context._

Comment: and this is the new code that i write:
`var user1 = Identitydb.Users.AsNoTracking();

 var specificUser = user1.ToList().Where(x => x.Email.StartsWith(model.Email));
 specificUser.Select(x => x.LockoutEnabled).Equals(false);

 //user.LockoutEnabled = false;

 //Identitydb.Users.Attach(user);   <--- I tried this solution also but it is not work

 Identitydb.Entry(specificUser).State = EntityState.Modified;


                Identitydb.SaveChanges();`